# Insert select working and mload failing

Tags: teradata, mload

I am facing one issue where I am able to insert into a table using normal insert select. However, when i am using the multiload to load the same table the records goes into the error table with the Error 6706: Untranslatable character error.

The column PROD_NAME is defined as UNICODE and arabic values along with numbers and % is coming into that column when doing a normal insert select.

My question is why is that not failing for normal insert select and failing in mload.

Also, how can i handle that in mload?

Thanks.

Comment: @dnoeth can you please provide your comments to this?

Comment: Need details - table definitions and scripts would be a good start. Are both sessions running with the same characteristics? This way when @dnoeth arrives he has some more to work with. ;)